# Projecting a grid on a 2d plane

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, plane-geometry

Unsure if this is the right network to post this, but maybe someone can help...

I'm working on a personal project where, with the help of AI, I want to automatically estimate the perspective of a given image.

I've been able to programatically estimate the position of the horizon, as seen below. This is based on how "quickly" cars farther away shrink in the image.

[image]

Not sure the above is useful, but now I want to draw a grid on the plane. Something like:

[image]

This is where it's getting too complicated for me. I have no idea how to solve this. Not the drawing per se, but the mathematics behind it.

I first thought I needed to find the plane equation based on the coordinates of the bottom left and bottom right corners of each box, since these are the ones intersecting the plane (the tires touching the road).

I did manage to find the equation `ax + by + cy + d`, but I am not sure I am on the right track. Looking for some guidance if anyone has any ideas.

---

EDIT:

Just to clarify the unknowns:

- Distance to any object or horizon.
- Physical size of objects (in meters or otherwise)
- Height or angle of camera

Comment: Try Cos(Lat) * Lon * K = x and Lat * K = y . Center of the grid is 0 longitude .

Comment: @SSpring thanks. Can you explain this a bit? :)

Comment: Latitude and longitude can be projected to a square grid but if a longitude line is plotted off the center then it plots as converging. The standard scale is one nautical mile per minute of latitude but the scale can be changed.

Comment: @SSpring by lat long you mean geographical lat long or x y coordinates from the center origin?

Comment: If the radius and scale of the latitude and longitude are changed then they are no longer geographical. Or maybe the local grid can be scaled to a large area of geographical latitude and longitude.

Comment: I suppose the AI-part is finding bounding boxes for the cars and you are now post-processing that data?

Comment: @String exactly! I managed to find the horizon (unsure if that is useful later on) by finding the average y-coordinate of intersects of lines going from bottom-left from car A to car B and top-right respectively. The rest, however, is beyond my skill and qualifications

Comment: @Chris: I do have some ideas. But some choices has to be made. You must decide some fixed width of a car, and a fixed height and width of the projected image on the screen. This will help determine the distances to each of the cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Projecting back to 3D-space

First, we have to set a couple of (somewhat arbitrary) constants in order to be able to translate bounding box sizes and 2D-positions to real world 3D-positions. For example
$$
\newcommand{\cm}{\operatorname{cm}}
\begin{align}
\operatorname{carwidth}&=200\cm\\
\operatorname{screen}&=30\cm\times20\cm\\
\operatorname{screendist}&=60\cm\\
\end{align}
$$
So here we assume that the focal point of the eye watching "through" the window of the screen is placed at a distance of $60\cm$ from the center of the screen. Let the eye be the origin of the coordinate system $(0,0,0)$

Now suppose some car has a bounding box with bottom corners at $C_1=(x_1, y_1)$ and $C_2=(x_1+10\cm,y_2)$ in centered screen coordinates. Then we have the two embedded 3D-points:
$$
\begin{align}
C_1&=(x_1,y_1,60\cm)\\
C_2&=(x_1+10\cm,y_2,60\cm)
\end{align}
$$
And we can simply rescale those positions by a factor:
$$
\frac{200\cm}{10\cm}=20
$$
in order to get the corresponding positions of the car in 3D-space:
$$
\begin{align}
P_1&=(20x_1,20y_1,1200\cm)\\
P_2&=(20x_1+200\cm,20y_2,1200\cm)\\
\end{align}
$$

**NOTE**: Here we have assumed that each bottom point of a car is at the same $z$-distance to the observer. If we use the top points too, we might be able to derive inclinations of cars too, but that becomes a different model.

### Estimating the common plane

Suppose we have done this to all the bottom point of a series of cars. Now we want to determine the approximate common plane for those. First we compute the mean of all the points (since any square minimizing solution will pass through the mean):
$$
M:=\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N P_i
$$
Then we minimize the square distances:
$$
Squares(a,b,c)=\sum\frac{(ax_i+by_i+cz_i-aM_x-bM_y-cM_z)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}
$$
for some limited search space of potential normal vectors $\langle a,b,c\rangle$. For instance we can choose the serach space to be $\langle a, 1, c\rangle$, so that we only consider normal vectors pointing at least partly upwards. This should be possible to either solve or approximate. This should provide you with a plane equation:
$$
ax+by+cz+d=0
$$
where $d=-aM_x-bM_y-cM_z$.

### Projecting the resulting grid

Again, we need to make a choice. For example, do you want the grid in 3D-space to be $100\cm\times 100\cm$. Once this has been decided, all you need to know is that lines in 3D are projected to becomes lines in 2D, so just compute some lattice points in the plane in 3D-space, project those to 2D-space by shortening by a factor that renders the z-coordinate equal to $60cm$ and draw a grid line through them on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. Instead of screendist I assume we could just use the focal length of the camera? I don't see how screendist is a variable here

Comment: @Chris: I agree - screendist only serves the purpose to place the focal point at some distance to the 2D-plane in order to compute scaled z-distances of 3D-objects. So focal length makes sense! I hope it pans out in practice :o)

Comment: @Chris: Also, the actual magnitude of carwidth is not of major importance. If you change it all just scales accordingly so you build a "different size model" of the entire 3D-space.

Comment: yes, I thought so too. They are all sizes relative to each other, since we are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @Chris: Correct. It is a fascinating problem, so feel free to post a comment at some point telling us how it went.

Comment: @Chris: BTW, the intersection of the grid lines would be a more stable estimate of the horizon, I suspect.

Comment: absolutely. It might take a few days though :) I don't think the horizon is where the grid lines intersect. The horizon is below that, I believe due to the curvature of the earth - so it's not an "actual" infinity here.

Comment: @Chris: If you project 3D-lines on 2D-space, lines moving away from you will meet much sooner than one might think. The curvature can probably not catch up with that in any significant way, I suspect. I am not sure, though.

Comment: When rescaling the points by a factor, you did 200/10. What is 10 here?

Comment: @Chris: That is the width of the car in the image on the screen. This gives us the ratio between the actual width of the car and the width of the screen representation. Had this measure only been say $5cm$, then the car would have been at twice the distance from the focal point and we would have scaled the screen positions by a factor $40$ instead. Hopefully this helps to clarify.

Comment: Thanks @String. I've gotten as far as calculating the mean. However, I don't understand how to calculate the square distances. What is a,b,c in this context? Do I need to select _any_ 3 cars or do I need to do this for each car? I'm doing this programatically, so it's a bit different :)

Comment: @Chris: It is a regression problem "Find an equation of a plane that best matches a swarm of points". You could google **plane equation regression**. The default core principle of regression is to sum all the squared errors (the distances from each point in the swarm to the suggested plane) and adjust parameters a, b and c to minimize the sum of squared errors.

Comment: @Chris: In this sense, a, b and c are inputs to a function in three variables that we want to minimize - they are not known beforehand as those are the numbers the computer regression algorithm should optimize.

Comment: gotcha. Would we not want to input more than just 3 variables? Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris: It is confusing, I know, but you want ALL the points as constant input. The three variables a, b, and c moves the plane around to fit all the other data input (so-calld feature input) of your system, which is ALL the bottom points from ALL the cars. So there are many inputs, but only three variable inputs that you optimize with respect to.

Comment: @Chris: And as stated in my answer, you cannot optimize with respect to a, b, and c - you have to limit this space, since $\vec n=\langle a,b,c\rangle$ constitutes a normal vector to the plane we are finding, and any scaled copy of $\vec n$ will yield the exact same plane. Hence we need to restrict to for instanace $b=1$ and only optimize wrt. $a,c$.

Comment: alright. Sorry for being slow here. So the actual variables are a and c. I'll let b = 1. The points from the cars will be input for x, y and z and each car summated. From what I understand, this solution relies on some initial guesses for a and c?

Comment: Chris: Yes, you need an initial guess for $a$ and $c$ (for instance $a=c=0$) OR some mathematical analysis to go straight to the minimum, since the function is a "simple" two dimensional quadratic function in $a$ and $c$ and has a min-point that could be found analytically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118456/discussion-between-chris-and-string).

Answer (score 0):

Or just calculate whatever lane direction is needed with Cos(direction) * Distance = y and Sin(direction) * Distance = x . North is 0 degrees direction while East is positive 90 degrees direction and West is negative 90 degrees direction. The coordinates are "forwards", polar style, from the origin coordinates and are netted with the origin coordinates for the overall x-y result. Or directly "forward" each lane direction from each beginning lane position.

An "inverse" between two pairs of coordinates of the same lane gives the lane direction. That's InverseTan((x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)) . If (x2 - x1) is negative then that is West otherwise it's East. If (y2 - y1) is negative then that is South otherwise it's North.